# Как определить алгоритм цифровой подписи

Tags: signature

Есть устройство, отправляющее следующие данные на свой сервер:

`AuthentificationRandomness: 12758A63-794E-4925-83DE-BCDACBCFA241
SignAuthRequest:VtTu6+LJ9ZcZH7RpUCDlHg==`

А в ответ принимает:

`AuthTicket: 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\n`

`AuthRequestSignature:JxFDkWahglmwdRO/3IoA0A==`

Помогите определить алгоритм цифровой подписи.

1. Каждый раз при попытке отправить на сервер те же данные получаю
   разные значения.
2. Похоже `AuthTicket` - это сертификат или публичный ключ. Посмотрел
   изнутри 1024 битовая. Но какой алгоритм использован, не смог
   определить.
3. Настолько я знаю это не `RSA` - подпись слишком короткий. Может это
   `ЕCDSA`, но какой тип?

Добавка:
Добавив -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- и -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY----- к AuthTicket и пропустив через DumpASN получил приватный ключ, но все равно алгоритм остается неизвестным. Пишет sha1WithRSAEncryption  - но сигнатура очень короткая.

`0 397: SEQUENCE {`

`4   1:   INTEGER 1`

`7  11:   SEQUENCE {`

`9   9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER sha1WithRSAEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 5)`

`:     }`

`20  88:   SET {`

`22   4:     [63] 05 1B A3 FB`

`29   4:     [64] E1 10 6F 00`

`36  20:     [75] 16 38 55 02 2A 1D EA C6 12 B9 3B AA 51 49 DF 29 30 12 C3 DF`

`59   7:     [1005] 01 34 11 00 37 48 35`

`70  12:     [3005] 00 00 00 00 EE EE EE EE EE EE EE EF`

`86   4:     [3006] 00 00 00 00`

`94   4:     [3007] 01 00 00 00`

`102   4:     [3008] 01 00 00 00`

`:     }`

`110 128:   OCTET STRING`

`:     99 10 30 58 69 E3 D1 CA 3E 69 91 C9 08 14 44 2E`

`:     F4 63 14 24 26 8E AC 46 BD 2F CF D3 49 B3 4F C7`

`:     B0 0B C2 DB 29 00 E0 43 6E 61 44 4A 63 5E 6D 3F`

`:     2B 4C 70 E2 0E D0 58 21 C0 91 67 F2 34 D0 4B E7`

`:     10 4E 5D 3D 1B 6C 9E 30 4C 37 99 F0 F6 B1 7F E2`

`:     1F 4E BB 6C 2C 01 C1 C1 2F 28 DF B2 2F 2C 33 4F`

`:     4D D0 9E 4E 45 89 40 D3 39 DE 04 30 04 CB 84 53`

`:     FD C0 5F 9B 0C F4 56 BC 2B F4 F9 C5 BF 12 59 F9`

`241 157:   [3] {`

`244  11:     SEQUENCE {`

`246   9:       OBJECT IDENTIFIER rsaEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 1)`

`:       }`

`257 141:     BIT STRING, encapsulates {`

`261 137:       SEQUENCE {`

`264 129:         INTEGER`

`:           00 ED 3A 3F 64 D1 E8 20 9C C1 52 06 34 EF 7E 2F`

`:           B2 09 7E 00 2C 43 43 E7 F8 AA EB E6 4A B3 C0 B6`

`:           00 C4 35 26 70 69 5A C7 5E 91 7E 71 12 81 00 1A`

`:           A4 0D AD 34 61 C1 0D C7 67 6D 4B 5B 6E 1C B2 83`

`:           36 7D 73 31 92 DA 65 1A 62 2B D5 1E 88 C3 CD 64`

`:           BE A6 96 0D 76 05 62 F0 56 39 45 38 61 03 F1 4E`

`:           A9 7D 7C 0E C3 A0 FF 14 20 D1 82 FC 86 06 7E F0`

`:           B3 0F 2C 11 AE C0 76 56 26 30 71 A6 92 FC 20 38`

`:           FD`

`396   3:         INTEGER 65537`

`:         }`

`:       }`

`:     }`

`:   }`

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы только на русском языке, переведите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если пропустить AuthTicket через ASN.1 парсер, получится:

```
Integer - 1
Sequence
    - Algorithm Identifier - 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5 (SHA1-with-RSA-Signature)
Set
    - 4 байта
    - 4 байта
    - 20 байт (SHA1 хеш?)
    - 7 байт
    - 12 байт
    - 4 байта
    - 4 байта
    - 4 байта
Octet String (128 байт, возможно здесь подпись)
Context Specific
    Sequence
        Sequence
            Object Identifier - 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 (RSA Encryption)
        Bit String (140 байт, возможно здесь публичный ключ длиной 1024 бита)
```

Если мне не изменяет память, это похоже на Cryptographic Message Syntax подпись (раньше называлась PKCS7). Но нужно смотреть уже ближе.

Comment: Буду благодарен если найдете время посмотреть поглубже

Comment: Почему вы думаете что подпись слишком короткая? Фактически длина самой подписи = длине публичного ключа. Если у вас 1024 бита, значит сама подпись это 128 байт.

Comment: Да но если декодировать данный AuthRequestSignature с base64 то получаем 16 байт информацию в hex, а не 128. Вот именно из за этого какая та не стыковка.

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что именно там подпись? Это могут быть просто данные, которые подписаны.

Comment: Имена переменных- думаете они ложные? SignAuthRequest и AuthRequestSignature

Comment: Я не знаю, я вам дал подробное направление, в котором смотреть, я не буду всю работу делать за вас. Это проверить несложно. Более того, я дал вам ответ на вопрос, это RSA подпись. Никакая подпись не поместится в 16 байт, даже самые старые элиптические кривые 112-битные, подпись на такой кривой будет занимать где-то 30 байт.

Comment: Конечно спасибо Вам за наводку, но это не полный ответ. И самое главное я до сих пор не понял схему реализации подписании. На счет 16 байта вот тут в ответах тоже упоминается об ECDSA. Не могли бы взглянуть и дать совет? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246362/looking-for-signing-algorithm-that-creates-32-or-16-byte-keys-in-java а вот тут список алгоритмов для явы чем можно подписать и куча из них выдают результат в 16 байтах https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/Signature.html

Comment: У новичков здесь всегда неполный ответ, до того времени, пока не сделаешь всю работу за них. stackoverflow - это место, где помогают с решениями проблем, а не решают за вас.

Comment: Согласен. Но все равно пасибо большое.

Comment: Для того, что бы выразить спасибо, есть кнопки возле ответов, ответ полезный/неполезный. Не нужно писать в комменты. Те алгоритмы для джавы формально не являются подписями, это или хеши, или MAC'и.